# Please explain this theorem with picture

Tags: intuition, convex-optimization

I logically understand this theorem, but I don't intuitively understand with picture.

> Let $S$ be a nonempty convex open set in $\mathbb R^n$ and let $f\colon S\to\mathbb R$ be differentiable on $S$. Then $f$ is convex if and only if for each $x_1,x_2\in S$ we have
>   $$[\nabla f(x_2)-\nabla f(x_1)]^t(x_2-x_1)\ge 0. $$
>   Similarly, $f$ is strictly convex if and only if for each distinct $x_1,x_2\in S$ we have
>   $$[\nabla f(x_2)-\nabla f(x_1)]^t(x_2-x_1)> 0. $$

Comment: What theorem?$\ $

Comment: I attached the image, but it is not working

Comment: Got it. I don't understand the notation, though. What's the apostrophe?

Comment: Jack M could you see the theorem?

Comment: Jack M : I think the apostrophe might actually be a "t", indicating transpose, if the gradients are column vectors.

Comment: It's a $t$, standing for transpose, which in this case signifies a dot product.

Comment: yes, that is "t" for transpose.

Comment: You should use Latex instead of pictures in future posts.

Answer (score 1):

It's telling you that the gradient spreads out in all directions so that the more you move in one direction, the more the gradient points in that same direction.
[image: Let's see if this shows]

Comment: What did you use to make this? It looks nice.

Comment: :-) A tablet pc with an ancient program called Windows Journal